# Methodology for comparing a deterministic and stochastic regression algorithm

Tags: regression, cross-validation, algorithms

I am trying to compare two different algorithms for performing regression. One of the algorithms (call it A) is deterministic, i.e. given the same training data and test data it will always produce the same predictions, while the other one (call it B) is stochastic, i.e. it will produce a different model each time it is run with the same training data and therefore produce different predictions on the same test data.

I am using a leave-one-out-cross-validation (LOOCV) methodology to compare A and B and measuring the accuracy of each algorithm on the same data. The problem is that while A and B have similar accuracies, the standard error for B is much higher than it is for A. However, since B is stochastic, I can perform multiple LOOCV experiments on B and get different predictions each time so that the standard error on B's accuracy can be reduced.

My question is, is this a valid/legitimate approach? In other words, can I compare the results of a 1 x LOOCV experiment on A to a N x LOOCV experiment on B where N is chosen such as that the standard error around B's accuracy is reduced to an acceptable level?

Comment: Personally I would prefer to use several (dozens of) tests of B and get a sense of both the central tendency and tendency of variation of its error.  Then I would be more okay with a comparison to A.